# Open & Close Menu with the same button (Closing not working)

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, menu

I'm trying to make an overlay menu that opens and close with the click of the same menu. I've tried using some solutions I've seen on this forum but the code I currently have only opens the menu and doesn't close it?

```
document.getElementById("botaomenu").addEventListener("click", toggleNav);

function toggleNav(){
    navSize = document.getElementById("myNav").style.width;
    if (navSize == 20) {
        return close();
    }
    return open();
}
function open() {
        document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "20%";
}
function close() {
         document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0";
}
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Santos1600/j2L7yga5/1/

I've already got the menu working while using a different button to close the menu, but I would prefer it, from a design point of view, if the same button did both actions on click.

Comment: close() is not being executed because in the condition you are comparing a string to an int : Try using if( parseInt(navSize) == 20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an error in width calculation

```
function toggleNav() {
 navSize = document.getElementById("myNav").offsetWidth;
 if (navSize > 0) {
  return close();
 }
  return open();
}
```

---

If you need it to close after clicking on the different entries
you have 2 options: 
1) you can close the menu if you click in any link by just adding

```
onclick="toggleNav();"
```

to the specific links.

2) Or in a more generic way, add a class on links ex "mylink"

and

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
if (evt.target.className === 'mylink') {
   toggleNav();
}
}, false);
```

in your code

Comment: If I needed it to close after clicking on the different entries of the list, would that be possible?

Comment: Added to my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  https://jsfiddle.net/reyq2064/

```
// document.getElementById("botaomenu").addEventListener("click", toggleNav);

function toggleNav() {
   navSize = document.getElementById("myNav").style.width;
   if (navSize == '20%') {
      return close();   
   }
   return open();
}
```